# How To Export Tools With Multiple Parts To Unity?

Tags: export, unity, origin

To start out I want to preface that I already know how to export FBX files from Blender to Unity. I know that you need to apply all transformation data before you export. I know that the object needs to face the Blender -Y axis so it faces the front in Unity. And finally I also know that the object needs to have it's bottom aligned so that it's bottom is resting on 0,0,0 so that it isn't through the bottom of the Unity world.

What I don't know is how to export tools with multiple parts from Blender to Unity. See there are certain parts are connected to tools need to be animated in Unity. One tool has wheels that need to be exported and animated in Unity so that they roll, however I cannot apply the transformation data in a way the pivot point does not move to the world origin, the pivot point moving back to the world origin is what is messing these parts up. One tool for example has a single mesh that's composed of 2 Cylinders on opposite ends of the tool to represent plastic wheels, the pivot point needs to be centered between the two wheels so that they can rotate in Unity. Another tool has 3 parts, a handle, a connection point, and the bottom of it that can be best described as a school janitor's wide mop. The parts above the main one at the bottom need exporting but their pivot points cannot change as that would make animating a functional version impossible.

What I need to know is if there's a way to export multiple objects, and apply the transformation data so that they're at Unity's 0,0,0 and have no transformation data on export without moving where their pivot points are. I really don't want to have to animate these in Blender and then export them as the process of doing that is a bit more complicated than what I'm used to so I'm looking for solutions and workarounds.